# Why document.ready waits?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that Document.ready  - **DONt** wait for images to download.

So **why** it does here ?

http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/27/edit#source

(after **each** test - change the **v**=xxx in the img **SRC**)

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('0');
         });

    </script>

    </head>
      <body  >
        <img src='http://musically.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Google-Logo.jpg?v=42333'  />

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a `script` tag in the `html` tag. Either put it in the `head` or the `body` tag. Things like that can make browsers act up...

Comment: still not working , read my comments bellow with POINTY

Comment: Didn't really expect it to work from that, that's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer. Just one thing to remove from the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem comes out from JSBin.com

Because, when you try this example on JSFiddle.net, it works properly

http://jsfiddle.net/vqte9/

Comment: @Pointy what you've posted is not `alert` but `setting a text`, alert works fine only on JSFiddle

Comment: Ah well that's possible, though it's not at all clear to me how jsbin could possibly cause such a problem.  It's the browser itself that's interpreting the page, after all.  I do see the effect though, so clearly *something* is going on.

Comment: Check the update to my answer - for me, I get different results based on how the ready handler is set up.

Comment: @Pointy , i get different behavior too

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that you're using "alert()", I think, though I'm not 100% sure why.  If you change your code like this:

```
  <body>
    <div id='x'></div>
    <img ...>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(function() { $('#x').text("hello there"); });
  </script>
```

you'll see that the text is filled in before the image loads.

*edit* — I don't know why this would make a difference, but I notice quite different behavior when I set up the ready handler with:

```
$(function() { whatever; });
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function() { whatever; });
```

Now that's not supposed to be the case; the two forms are supposed to do exactly the same thing, as far as I know.  However, they don't seem to.  [Here](http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/33/edit) is a jsbin example that sets up the ready handler with the first form, and [here](http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/34/edit) is one that uses the second one.  They behave very differently for me.  I'll have to check the jQuery source to figure out how that can be true.

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) is the jQuery documentation explaining the equivalence of `$(handler)` and `$(document).ready(handler)`.

Comment: You may be right that it has something to do with jsbin, but even there if you change the code so that you don't use "alert()" you'll see that it's working as you expect (that is, that the "ready" code runs before the image loads).

Comment: how can i test it ...? with document.write ?

Comment: Look at the example in my answer. Instead of using "alert()", have your "ready" handler do something directly to the page.

Comment: javascript: console.log(2); - didnt work neither. instead of the alert.

Comment: OK.  Well, maybe you could try the example I gave in my answer :-)

Comment: doesnt work neither.  http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/30/edit  the progblem is with jsbin . PERIOD. ;)

Comment: No, you didn't do what I said, at least not exactly. You put my code (which already is a "ready" handler) inside *another* ready handler.  [Here is the correct version](http://jsbin.com/ehuke4/32/edit) and it works fine for me.